# Link Docker containers running on different hosts?

Tags: docker

I'm starting in container based archictectures with Docker and I have a doubt that maybe is a nonsense.

Has it sense to link Docker containers that are running on different hosts?

Say we have two containers:

1. `barDatabase`
2. `fooService`

If both are in the same host, we would link the `barDatabase` to `fooService` giving, this way, a hostname to communicate between them.

But if they are running on different machines:

1. `barDatabase` -> `machine1.company.local`
2. `fooService` -> `machine2.company.local`

Would be yet necessary to link them? Couldn't we use the original hostname without link them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Newer versions of Docker have the docker network - this requires a bit of extra config, like - for example - an `etcd` to manage the config.

In doing so, you can then:

```
docker network create sometnetname
docker run -d --net somenetname --name barDatabase yourimage
```

And on your other host:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --net somenetname --name fooService service_image
```

You'll then be able to 'ping' barDatabase as if it was a hostname, from fooService. And fooService will attach to the external net, and act as a gateway.

This works on my `1.9.1` docker, and not on my `1.8.2` - on centos. (So I would assume it's a 1.9+ feature, but I can't find a direct source).

More detail:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/

Requires a bit more faff to set up though, because you do have to configure etcd (or another key value store)

I've been using this to put a multi-node elasticsearch instance on a private network, which I would assume is similar to your use case. (3 es nodes on 3 hosts, with logstash feeding in, and kibana acting as a gateway, along with an nginx admin proxy that does some security/rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you'd have to expose the ports you want access from the database container in machine1, and then in machine2 you'd just point to machine1 at the exposed port, as you expected. There's no need (and AFAIK no way) to directly link the containers from different machines.